# why google cloud compute engine 100x slower than a dedicated server with lower spec on numpy.dot operation

Tags: numpy, google-compute-engine

I'm running some numpy dot product test on google cloud
google cloud compute engine shows 100x slower speed than dedicated server with lower CPU and memory spec when doing numpy.dot operation.
I was thinking about transfer all my systems to google cloud but it seems it is not possible with this poor performance.
Is there any way to improve it ?

Dedicated server spec:
- Intel Core i3 2120
- 16GB Memory
numpy.dot time: 0.7363626956939697 seconds

Google Cloud compute engine spec:
n1-highmem-8 (8 vCPUs, 52 GB memory)
numpy.dot time: 92.44161581993103 seconds

Comment: Basic question - is numpy compiled against similar blas/lapack libraries on both machines?

Comment: I simply installed numpy on both server with this command:   pip3 install numpy

Comment: I would check `np.show_config()` to see what libraries numpy is configured with. I'm guessing you have an optimized blas/lapack implementation on the dedicated server, but not on the Google Cloud Compute machine.

Comment: you are right,  optimized blas/lapack implementation were not on google part

Comment: @VY If you have resolved this issue can you post your solution as an answer, so that other users with the similar question can get some help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was solved by
1. use np.show_config() found gce server did not have blas installed
2. then run following command solved the problem

```
sudo pip3 uninstall numpy 
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev -y
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: On mine it says it has openblas, but not blas_mkl (Intel Math Kernal Library). Was yours missing openblas, or was it missing the Intel MKL?